# To whom does Tony Soprano's line "We all know Vito’s not the first." refer?

Tags: the-sopranos

In the clip *Tony, Silvio And Carlo Discuss Vito* linked below, Carlo Gervasi makes the case that Vito Spatafore should be killed for being known to be a homosexual.

To support the plausibility that Vito could be kept alive and his utility exploited in some other way, Tony Soprano counters:

> Carlo, let’s be honest with ourselves here. We all know Vito’s not the first.

(I think there has been at least one other reference to "not the first" but I can't recall where.)

In this scene is Tony referring to someone in The Sopranos "universe" or to a historical figure beyond the TV Series?

---

**note:** I don't know what episode this is from, but if it postdates Gandolfini's portrayal of a gay hitman in the movie [The Mexican](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mexican) it could be seen as an oblique reference to that I suppose. Just idle speculation.

Comment: I don't know the show but it may be a reference to John d'Amato: https://www.theguardian.com/world/2003/may/02/usa.garyyounge